# How do I add jquery-mobile to a rails 4 app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

My goal is moving between previous and next photos in mobile browser with a finger swipe:

https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipeleft/

https://api.jquerymobile.com/swiperight/

Since I am only going to be using it in a few areas of the website, I decided to place:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
```

at the top of my `show.html.erb` view.

However, it completely destroys/crashed the way that my web app looks and functions. For example, buttons that I had hidden were displayed. Elements were over and undersized, etc.

In [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119190/turbolinks-wipes-out-jquery-mobile-classes) it is suggested that Turbolinks must be removed. I am not sure if that is the source of these problems.

```
application.html.erb

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 
                                              'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    </div>
   </body>
</html>

application.js

//= require jquery2
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require dropzone
//= require select2-full 
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require selectize

application.css

*= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
 *= require dropzone/dropzone
 *= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap
 *= require selectize
 *= require selectize.default
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

Comment: Try removing just the CSS file.  If you're only going to use the jQuery swipe functions, you don't need it

Comment: This solves the css problems. However, I am still having problems with what I guess is the turbolinks issue. For example, if I go from example.com/photos/1 to example.com/photos/2 it continues to show me photo 1 on the example.com/photos/2 page

Comment: According to that post you referenced.  The two are not meant to work together.  Use one or the other.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup would you like to submit as answer for approval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the post you referenced, Turbolinks and jQuery are not meant to be used together.  On top of that, if you're just using the jQuery Mobile `swipe` functions, you don't need any styling, so remove the CSS file for jQueryMobile and try that.